# Fit a dataframe into a predefined grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of 1110 observation, also I created a grid of 1110 subareas of one plot to fit the data in each of those little blocks. How can I do that in r using ggplot?

```
type here
```

I don't know how to proceed but I'm expecting to have each value in every block here

[image]

Comment: Add to your data frame columns for the x and y coordinates of the centers of your blocks would be a good start. If you want help, please make a small reproducible example, say 10 blocks, and share the data and any information you can about the blocks.

Comment: Actually, each observation in my dataframe has the coordinates of the centroids of each block in the grid.

Comment: The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()`, `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data.